# How to test location based iPhone application for pre development or beta testing from desktop?

Tags: iphone, gps, core-location

I want to test my Location based application that uses CLLocationManager to find my current locaiton and perform other operations.

Please let me know how can i test it

Comment: you cannot test your location based app from your system,it is not supported in simulator. You need to test it on device to fetch latitude and longitude values.

Comment: Sarah, that's not true, if you're using Xcode4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked out the following two URL and this may help you.

[testing GPS in iPhone simulator problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370289/testing-gps-in-iphone-simulator-problem)

[iPhone Simulator providing location results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060954/iphone-simulator-providing-location-results)

There are tools for this tasks as well; you can check out the following for the same.

http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/faq/

Comment: hi Jigar,
Great Answer but i can not getting any help using this site.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 4.2 you can simulate locations right from your debugger:
[image: Press this button, when in debug mode]
[image: Location simulation menu]

Comment: I have XCode 4.2 but not seeing this on the toolbar as shown in the picture?  Ah -- you have to be running iPhone 5.0 Simulator and then it shows up!